# T-SQL: is there a way to force conformance to ANSI SQL?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, ssis, migration

We are planning on writing a load process that uses SSIS and loads a SQL 2008 database. Transformations may be done in the packages or in stored procedures that are called from a package or directly from our job scheduler.

What can we do now while in planning stage to minimize the impact should we have to migrate the app to Oracle in teh future?

I picture the SSIS packages could be changed to use a different provider.

What about the SQL that we use?

Q: Is there a way to put, for example, a stored procedure in "ANSI mode" for lack of a better term to ensure that only standard SQL is used within to increase our chances that the SQL will migrate to Oracle?

Comment: Not sure why some random person has voted to close this as Off Topic.  Seems very programming related to me.

Comment: There has been an ongoing discussion over recent weeks in my office about related topics.  I will be watching this question.  1 upvote from me.

Comment: The data source is probably a CSC text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is `SET FIPSFLAGGER FULL` etc.  More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189781.aspx

Comment: Interesting. I was hoping for some option that might be at a level lower than the database level, but this is still of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any ANSI Standard for RDBMS programming languages.  And the constructs between TSQL and PL/SQL are quite different.

But can you use the Common Runtime Environment (I think that's what its called) in SQL Server to run JAVA?  If you can, and given that Oracle can run JA VA this might offer a pathway to what you want to acheive.

Comment: Actually there is a standard: SQL/PSM (Persistent Stored Modules). But the DBMS vendors ignore that even more than the regular SQL standard. The only DBMS that implements at least parts of it, is DB2. And I think there was a proof of concept implementation for Postgres.

Comment: Well you learn something every day :)  I have never come across it and I see from a quick google that its not to widely implemented.